# PictureBox assigned ErrorImage is not shown after incorrectly Disposing its Image

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a winforms application where user can select an image from a list of available images and the corresponding image is shown in a PictureBox. The images can be very huge with a minimum of 10MB. This obviously makes the rest of the UI unresponsive while the image loads. So I thought of loading the image on a separate thread using the following code:

```
private void LoadImage()
{
    // loadViewerThread is a Thread object
    if (loadViewerThread != null && loadViewerThread.IsAlive)
    {
       loadViewerThread.Abort(); // Aborting the previous thread if the user has selected another image
    }
    loadViewerThread = new Thread(SetViewerImage);
    loadViewerThread.Start();
}
```

The SetViewerImage function is as below:

```
private void SetViewerImage()
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(/*Some stream*/);
}
```

After this the images load smoothly and the UI can also be accessed.
But if the user moves very fast between the set of images then a big red X mark comes up. This happens because I have that call to Dispose in **SetViewerImage**.

I have assigned an ErrorImage to the PictureBox but that ErrorImage is never shown in this case.

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with my thread implementation? Why does the
   Image gets disposed?
2. Is there any way that I can display a different ErrorImage and not
   the red X?

Comment: By general agreement the safest way to dispose of a `pb.Image` is this: `if (...) {Image temp = pictureBox1.Image; pictureBox1.Image = null; temp.Dispose(); }` Not sure if it helps but it is a first step to take.. - Also: You did notice the `InitialImage` property, yes? - And finally: You may consider simply disabling the list until the Image has completed loading..

Comment: On setting the Image property to null the picturebox is blank and doesn't show the custom ErrorImage. I can't disable the list of images. In my case the user should be allowed to move between the images.

Comment: _On setting the Image property to null the picturebox is blank and doesn't show the custom ErrorImage._ Of course, why would it? Null is not an error, just an empty PB.Even if you don't want to disable the list I would try to disable/abort any running thread when a new image has been picked until the ImageLoaded event has been reached.

Comment: @Taw can you provide some code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate controls in the UI thread. You can do this by using [Control.Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from a different thread.

The big bottleneck is creating the image from the stream, so you should be able to reorganize your method like this to keep the UI thread freed up:

```
private void SetViewerImage()
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(/* Some stream*/);

    pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;  // This might help? Only add if it does.
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
        }));
}
```

Comment: @itseme I didn't want to complicate the question too much, that's why I didn't post the call to Invoke. Since I am doing the manipulations on a diff thread so I have used that. I tried your suggestion to set Image to null. It didn't show the red X but the picturebox was blank. It didn't show the custom ErrorImage